# Show that $H = \bigcup_{n > 0} S_n$ is not equal to Sym$(X)$ for $X = \{1,2,3,4,...\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetry

Let $X = \{1,2,3...\}$ be the set of positive natural numbers, $S_n$ the permutation group, and Sym$(X)$ the set of all bijections from X to X with operation composition. I have the following questions.

1) How do I show that $H = \bigcup_{n > 0} S_n$ is a subgroup of Sym$(X)$, or how do I interpret this being a subgroup (in terms of compositions of bijections??).

2) How do I show that $H$ and Sym$(X)$ are not equal?

EDIT:

1) I have problems with the subgroup properties.

First property.
The identity element of $S_2$ is not equal to the identity element of $S_4$ for example. I see that both are bijective functions such that $f(x) = x$. But $S_2$ sends $(12) \to (12)$, but does nothing with $(1234)$, it's not in its domain? So how do I prove that there exists a $id_f \in H$, such that $id_f$ in all $S_n$, and that this one equals the one in $Sym(X)$.

Second property.
If $a,b \in \bigcup_{n > 0} S_n$, then $a,b \in S_i$ for some $i \leq n$, and thus $ab \in S_i$, and thus $ab \in \bigcup_{n > 0} S_n$. But what if $a$ and $b$ are not in the same $S_i$? I can only assume that the union of subgroups is a subgroup if $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset ... \subset S_n$.

Third property.
This one is easy.

2) At first I was confused because I thought that you can always find enough bijective functions in $H$. But each $S_n \in H$ has finite order, and thus works on finitely many elements in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus a function $f \in Sym(X)$ that works on all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ cannot be in $H$, even though (I believe) all $f \in Sym(X)$ have finite order too... I think I understand this part now.

Comment: Backing up a step, is it clear to you that $Sym(X)$ is a group with respect to function composition?  After you grasp that, it should be clear that the $S_n$ are a nested family of subgroups.  You can even come up with a very compact description of what portion of $Sym(X)$ is covered by the union of the $S_n$.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem at all understanding that Sym(X) is a group with respect to function composition. I just can't grasp how the union of infinite $S_n$ does not cover everything in $Sym(X)$... The infinite part is what makes it confusing.

Comment: The "infinite part" is exactly the key you need to spot that the $S_n$ don't cover everything.  Pick out a bijection in $Sym(X)$ that moves infinitely many of the positive natural numbers in $X$.  Ask yourself if it can be in any of the $S_n$ subgroups.

Comment: But there are infinitely many subgroups, why can't there be one in which there are infinitely many positive numbers moved? Where am I making a mistake in my thought process?

Comment: While there are infinitely many subgroups $S_n$, to belong to their union you have to belong to one of them.  And these subgroups are each finite permutations.

Comment: I've voted to re-open. The comments give sufficient context and thoughts on the problem from the OP.

Comment: I have given a more extensive explanation now. I'm still stuck so if the question can be re-opened, that would be great!

Comment: Thanks, it has now been reopened.  The issue of $S_n$ being a subset of $Sym(X)$ or even of $S_{n+1}$ is a legitimate concern.  We are "abusing" the notation by interpreting the finite symmetric groups $S_n$ as acting not only on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ but also on all of $X= \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ through the convention that any permutation in $S_n$ fixes (leaves unmoved) all the positive integers greater than $n$.  With this convention we have all the $S_n$ symmetry groups "embedded" in $Sym(X)$, and then the subgroup properties work out (identity means identity function on $X$).

Comment: Given a subset $A$ of $\mathbb N$ define a bijection $\sigma_A : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ that fixes the elements of $A$, and does not fix any element of $\mathbb N\setminus A$. For example, enumerate $\mathbb N \setminus A$ and swap the ones with odd label with the ones with even label. This gives a set embedding $2^{\mathbb N} \to Sym(\mathbb N)$, so the latter set is uncountable. Your union is countable.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Note that $H$ is the set of permutations of $X$ that have finite support in the sense that they move just a finite subset of $X$ and fix the rest.

The hint proves both points:

1. If $\sigma, \tau$ have finite support than so do $\sigma^{-1}$ and $\sigma\tau$. The identity clearly has finite support.
2. Not all permutations of $X$ have finite support. For instance, the one that swaps even and odd numbers does not.

Comment: Do they also move a finite set of $\mathbb{N}$ if the union is infinite?

Comment: @user260710. yes because each element in $H$ belongs to some $S_n$. And $S_n \subset Sym(X)$ by fixing every number greater than $n$.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your hint. Because how do I know that there does not exist a $S_n$ for every element in Sym$(X)$?

Comment: So Icould show that $f(x) = x + 1$ for $f \in$ Sym$(X)$ fails? Then for every $S_n$ I would miss one element if I understand correctly?

Comment: @user260710, $x \mapsto x+1$ is not a bijection because $1$ is not in the image.

Comment: My bad. I see how your suggested swap of the even and odd numbers works. Thank you!

Comment: Map the odds to the primes, and the evens to the rest, I doubt that has finite order.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any bijection of $X$ without fixed points. It is clear it cannot be in any of the $S_n$, since all these permutations have infinite fixed points when viewed as bijections of $X$. This proves the second claim.

For the first one, if you want to put a group structure on $\cup S_n$, you have to consider the canonical injections $i^m_n : S_m \to S_n$ $(m<n)$ that sends a permutation in the same permutation fixing all the excess points. When you do the union, you're viewing any element of $\cup S_n$ as an equivalence class where $w = \sigma$ if there is some $n,m$ such that $w=i^m_n ( \sigma)$ or $\sigma=i^m_n (w)$.
This is a complicate way to say that you're essentially considering $S_{i-1} \subset S_i$.

Now for any two elements $w, \sigma$ in $\cup S_n$ you have that $w  \in S_k$, $\sigma \in S_h$ for some $h,k$. Suppose wlog $h<k$ and define $\sigma \circ w$ as $i^h_k(\sigma) \circ w \in S_k$.
It follows that the identity element is $i^1_n(\operatorname{id})$ for any $n$.